# Expressing a polynomial as a sum of squares in Maple

Tags: polynomials, maple, sum-of-squares-method

While *sostools* in MATLAB would find such a sum of squares decomposition, I am wondering whether a similar package exists for Maple.

**Example.** Express the following polynomial as Sum Of Squares:$$\frac{16}{9}(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3-(a^3+3b^2c)^2-(3ac^2+b^3)^2-(3a^2b+c^3)^2?$$
Thanks for a real lot!